# MATCH_PARENT width not working

Tags: android, xml, width

I try to create a fragment with gravity end to use it with NavigationMenu but my problem is that match_parent not found because the fragment not full-screen width.

this is my xml:

```
<!-- The Right navigation drawer -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_filters"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:name="com.ui.newdesign.FilterNavigationFragment"/>
```

But the width is not match parent:

[image]

If any have idea please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: for navigation drawer you have to specify width ...as it is out of your main layout [check this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout)

Comment: Then as I can adjust the width to the width of the screen?

Comment: drawer is used to extra feature without disturbing current fragment...if you want to display it on full screen I would suggest to instead use another fragment and transit it....and yes with full width you wont be able to show shadow....

Comment: I display it with full width but wrap_content in the height, is not full screen

Comment: then replace it with match_parent